# Azure Devops: How to set group variable with if statement

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set the variable group according to one varible that exists in the pipeline. The yaml looks like this:

[image]

But i'm getting the following error when i'm running the pipeline:

[image]

If i remove the **"- group : QA"** or **"- group : PROD"** the pipeline runs without any problem. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

This is slightly different solution but you may achieve your goal - which is if I understood conditional selection of variable group.

You can use runtime parameters:

```
parameters:
- name: environment
  displayName: Environment
  type: string
  default: QA
  values:
  - QA
  - PROD

stages:
- stage:
  displayName: 'Build and Restore'
  variables:
  - group: ${{ parameters.environment }}
  jobs:
    - job:
      steps:
      - script: echo $(name)
```

than running a build you can select your envrionment:

[image: Running a build]

Note: I have defined two variable groups QA and PROD with variable name in both groups.

Comment: I really liked your approach! It worked pretty well, thanks!

Comment: this helped me out today, thanks!

Comment: I tried this, but then i realized that when i make a commit and the pipeline is set to trigger on that branch, the default is automatically selected.

Answer (score 6):

Try with below schema:

```
variables:
  isProd: true

stages:
- stage: Test
  displayName: Build and restore
  variables:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['isProd'], 'false') }}:
    - group: QA
  - ${{ if eq(variables['isProd'], 'true') }}:
    - group: PROD
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - bash: echo $(groupname)
```

[image]

***Note:*** You may receive some red warning when you defining above YAML scipt. Ignore that confused warning and continue to run it.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. What could I do wrong?
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
echo $(groupname)
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/f1c09eb7-1ef2-43ab-b0e6-7a4905c67b8d.sh
/home/vsts/work/_temp/f1c09eb7-1ef2-43ab-b0e6-7a4905c67b8d.sh: line 1: groupname: command not found


Finishing: Bash

Comment: @Krzysztof, does **QA** and **PROD** variable groups has been created in your **Library**?

Comment: Ok. So groupname is a variable inside a group, right? It is not a built in variable :)
All is ok. I made mistake assuming that groupname is a built in variable containing used groups.

Comment: @Krzysztof Nope,QA and PROD are just variable group names, they are not stored in any group. I mean you need make this variable group has been created like this: https://imgur.com/a/rr7z1sX

Comment: @ Merlin Liang - MSFT yes I know. My mistake was that I didn't create a groupname variable inside a groups QA and PROD. All is fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I managed to go with @Krzysztof answer, for the team it was better to use the parameters. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: @Bino It’s okay. It would be much better of you could accept Krzysztof’s answer:-)

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same thing with classic (non-YAML) pipeline ?

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar at the global level to dynamically set the variable group.

```yaml
variables:
    - ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release') }}:
      - group: Staging
    - ${{ elseif eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}:
      - group: Production
    - ${{ else }}:
      - group: Development
```

also added a variable in the variable group to identify which one was being set, then displayed using the below script:

```yaml
- script: |
    echo $(VARIABLE_GROUP_NAME)
  displayName: 'Selected Variable Group
```

Comment: Did this work ? what's the reason for defining variables insise variables ?

Comment: oh, thanks for pointing it out, that was a mistake on my part. I fixed it by removing the first "variable:", essentially removing the double variable nesting. Otherwise, yes it works

Comment: can I use this variable group name as parameter throughout the pipeline. At the end of pipeline run, I want to update the variable group.
```
variables:
- $ { { if startsWith (variables ['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/users') }}:
  - name: variableGroupName
    value: userbranches
- $ { { else }}:
  - name: variableGroupName
    value: $ [ variables ['Build.SourceBranchName'] ]
```

Comment: honestly, not sure. but from what i understand, the variable group can only be set once. However, you can refer to the variables you want within the that group throughout the pipeline after it has been set