# Dynamic variable group in azure

Tags: variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am stuck with the following.
Being trying to use a variable group in azure depending in the variable of an another vg. Example below:

```
variables:
- group: automation-marionette
- name: workingEnv
  value: $(variables.envName)
- group: $(workingEnv)


stages:
  - stage: test
    jobs:
      - job: test
        steps:
        - script: |
               echo 'envName: ' $(envName)
               echo $(VALUES_FILE)
```

even though I changed the variable call with many different ways , it never works.
I tried:

- $(variables.envName)
- $[variables.envName]
- $(variables['envName'])

but always I get the error:

> An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. Variable group  was not found or is not authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.

Permissions have been checked and the vg has no restrictions from pipelines and every user has admin rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this based on the variable, but you can use parameters instead

```yaml
parameters:
- name: environment
  displayName: Environment
  type: string
  default: QA
  values:
  - QA
  - PROD

stages:
- stage:
  displayName: 'Build and Restore'
  variables:
  - group: ${{ parameters.environment }}
  jobs:
    - job:
      steps:
      - script: echo $(name)
```

Take a look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60987682/2347999).

Using variable groups this is not possible. References by you link to the documentation presents different case

```
variables:
- group: my-variable-group
- name: my-passed-variable
  value: $[variables.myhello] # uses runtime expression

steps:
- script: echo $(myhello) # uses macro syntax
- script: echo $(my-passed-variable)
```

It uses a compile-time expression for setting variable group `- group: my-variable-group` and runtime expression for setting variable.

In this step here `- group: $(workingEnv)` you try to use the runtime expression to set the variable group. And this is not possible. It has to be a compile-time expression.

As it is written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#process-the-pipeline):

> It also answers another common issue: why can't I use variables to resolve service connection / environment names? Resources are authorized before a stage can start running, so stage- and job-level variables aren't available. Pipeline-level variables can be used, but only those variables explicitly included in the pipeline. Variable groups are themselves a resource subject to authorization, so their data is likewise not available when checking resource authorization.

There is a mistake in documentation. It is possible to set value for variable but it is not possible to set variable group name in [this way](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-reference-variable-groups-with-parameter/847588#TPIN-N924828)

> This is likely a case that can be fixed by using a different kind of expression.
> In our yaml language, we have a few kinds of expressions that are evaluated at different points in the execution of a pipeline.
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops
>
> If you are using variables to reference resources, those will need to be “compile time constants”, or at least knowable at the start of a stage when resources are auth’d.
>
> In your case, I expect switching to the compile-time expression ${{}} will solve your issue. In a release of AzureDevops which is currently deploying, we are adding new functionality to increase the power of ${{}} expressions. I expect that even if the ${{}} do not work for you at the moment, they will starting with the rollout of process parameters.

The variable group is a resource and it has to be a compile-time expression.

Comment: Hi Krzysztof! thanks for your answer. I am aware of this solution.
What I am trying to do is, I am modifying a vg on an another pipeline and triggering the pipeline shown above with different variable {envName} everytime.
Do you by any chance know if thats possible? Microsoft documentation shows that this is possible, but it doesnt work for me
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Where `variables.envName` does come from? is it `group: automation-marionette`?

Comment: yes thats correct. this vg has a variable named 'envName'

Comment: It is not possible. Please check my edited reply.

Comment: I see. This means Microsoft Doc, is incorrect then? or is it for an another purpose. I am kinda confused here.

Comment: @ChrisTsag Could you check my edit?

Comment: Hey Krzys, many thanks for the links you provided! I can just accept that this doesnt work for now. I went for an another straight forward solution.